# Compare the characters in two strings regardless of their position

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a function `similarity(s, t)` that compares two strings and the elements of said strings, regardless of their position, and returns the number of identical elements. The code I have:

```
def similarity(s, t):
   return sum(s == t for s, t in zip(s, t))
```

The only issue is that tests such as:

```
similarity('ab','ba') == 2
```

fail. I guess because it's only checking the first elements, and returning that result. Is there anyway to get around this whilst using `zip()` or should I take the more arduous route?

Comment: You may want `return sum(s == t for s, t in zip(sorted(s), sorted(t)))`. Even then, I don't know if you are dealing with strings of the same length. If not, then `zip_longest` from the `itertools` module may come in handy, instead of `zip`. But it still would not be an all-encompassing solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The strings aren't of equal length, and it seems as though zip_longest isn't working for `similarity('aab','ba') == 2` that one's still returning 1 unfortunately..but doing `sorted(s), sorted(t)` did work for the ones of equal length, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def similarity(a, b):
    cnts1 = Counter(a)
    cnts2 = Counter(b)
    diff = cnts1 - cnts2
    return len(a) - sum(diff.values())

    # or if you want it as one liner:
    # return len(a) - sum((Counter(a) - Counter(b)).values())
```

Which should work correct:

```
>>> similarity('ab', 'ba')
2
>>> similarity('aba', 'bab')
2
```

The problem with `zip` is that it zips the elements by index, so you only compare items at the same position.